# problem with border-collapse property in IE7

Tags: html, css

I have a table with 2 rows and 2 cols.

```
1st row:
Col1 = 2 spans
Col2 = 3 Spans

2nd Row:
Col1 = 3 Spans
Col2 = 5 Spans
```

I have set `border-collapse` property of table to `Collapse`.I am getting borders for all cells except the last cell as it extends more than 1st row.I tried using `border-top-width:1px` and still it does not display the top boder for last cell.

Please help.

Thanks

~Anand

Answer (score 0):

Do every TD/TH have content inside? I mean not only tags (spans), but some text.

In which browsers do you have such problems?

Does your code look like this:

```
<style>
table {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

th, td {
   border: 1px solid #000;
}
</style>
```

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td>something></td>
        <td>something></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>something></td>
        <td>something></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Check which styles were applyed to TABLE and TD's in Firebug or DevelopersTool. Maybe some styles are overlapping your's.